# How to reduce space between letter mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I want reduce letter spacing using mpdf. Such as css having `letter-spacing` properties. Is mpdf have this properties?

Comment: try this link (https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<p  class="coloured bolded" style="font-size: 20pt;letter-spacing: -5pt; "> Simple text </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> [`letter-spacing  normal | LENGTH  (mPDF >= 5.1)`](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

Comment: Well, I'm using mPDF 8.0.2, tried using letter-spacing, which was completely ignored in the PDF, googled it and landed here.

I guess OP had a similar experience, only that he hasn't found a question with an insulting answer of somebody else. Which neither helps the OP nor anyone else like me.